# How to get Google API credentials from device in Phonegap?

Tags: android, cordova, google-api, google-calendar-api

Building a phonegap app for Android and I want to gain access to the device user's Google calendar credentials so that I can manipulate calendar events in JS.  There's lots of tutorials on how to deal with Google API's with static credentials but how do I grab those from the device itself on a per user basis?

Comment: Have a look at [Delegating Domain-wide authority](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority) from the Google documentation, it may be what you're looking for. Once you have this setup, your app can make Google API calls on behalf of the user. Hope this helps and Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get the credentials directly but you can use the calendar provider to operate on calendar data: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html